# Access Violation Exception with Linked Lists

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list, nodes

I am working on a Contact Book comprised of Nodes.

My goal is to print the linked list (from head to tail)
and write to a text file through my SaveContacts Method below.

Both of these Methods are a part of my Node's class.

**However, I am getting Access Violation Exceptions regardless of whether or not I include the try/catch/throw calls.**

**Exact Error :**

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
this->current was 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

---

**I have briefly looked into Access Violation Exceptions and discovered that typically it is a bad practice with few exceptions.**

**I have tried changing my compiler options from Ehs to Ehsc. Both resulted in the same error.**

---

### **Node.h**

```
class ContactBook
{
private:

public:

    // Pointers necessary for travesal and construction 
    // of the linked list
    AddressNode *head = nullptr;
    AddressNode *tail = nullptr;
    AddressNode *current = nullptr;
    AddressNode *newContact = nullptr;

    // Methods to add and print contacts
    void PrintForward();
    void InsertAtEnd();

    // Method to Save Contacts in a text file
    void SaveContacts();

    ContactBook();
    ~ContactBook();
};
```

### Node.cpp

Inserting Nodes into the Linked List

```
void ContactBook::InsertAtEnd()
{
    newContact = new AddressNode;

    newContact->CreateContact();

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = newContact;
        //head->prev = nullptr;

        tail = newContact;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->link = newContact;
        tail = newContact;

        tail->prev = tail;
    }
}
```

**Access Violation Exceptions happens here
WITH OR WITHOUT try/catch/throw**

Printing Method (Essentially the same as SaveContacts Method)

```
void ContactBook::PrintForward()
    {
        try
            {
                throw current = head;
            }   

        catch (...)
        {
            while (current->link != nullptr)
            {
                    current->PrintContactList();
                    cout << endl;

                    current = current->link;
                }
        }
    }
```

Writing to File Methods (Essentially the same as PrintForward Method)

```
void ContactBook::SaveContacts()
{
    throw current = head;

    try
    {
        // Honestly don't know what to insert here
    }

    // To catch any exception
    catch (...)
    {
        fstream file;
        file.open("SavedContacts.txt", ios::out);

        while (current->link != nullptr)
        {
            file >> current->PrintContactList();
            current = current->link;
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

---

### **Main.cpp**

```
#include "AddressNode.h"
#include "ContactBook.h"
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ContactBook contactBook;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        contactBook.InsertAtEnd();

        cout << "Hello, " << contactBook.newContact->GetName() << endl;
        cout << contactBook.newContact->PrintContactList();
    }

    system("cls");

    ///////////////////////////
    // EXCEPTION HANDLING????//
    ///////////////////////////

    contactBook.PrintForward();

    cout << "The end \n";

    //contactBook.SaveContacts();

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

### Could someone propose a viable solution based on the code provided below?

Comment: You should spend more time fixing your program instead of trying to catch read access violations.

Comment: `this->current was 0xCDCDCDCD.` This is a clue that you're dealing with an uninitialised value.

Comment: Now it's time to learn how to use your debugger which is a great help for finding bugs like that. The debugger in visual studio is really easy to use.

Comment: Post a [MCVE], then maybe someone can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your understanding of using exception handling is wrong. An example of a valid sequence would be:

```
try{
    code that might throw an exception
}
catch(exception){
    exception handling code
}
```

Your implementation does the processing in the catch clause which in wrong. Move the code to the try block.
The insertAtTheEnd function seems to be valid but the way you link "tail" to the previous element is wrong. A correct way to do this would be:

```
tail->link = newContact;
newContact->prev=tail;
tail = newContact;
```

For parsing your contact list you could something similar to:

```
current=head; //init the pointer with the head of the list
while (current != nullptr) //check if you have not reached the end of the list
{
    //process the current node
    current = current->link;
}
```

I do not guarantee that this will solve your problem but it will be a step in the right direction.